# initializing a class without running the constructor to test other methods with jest

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs

i have a class, that when a new instance is initialized, it calls a private validation method, however i want to test the validation method in isolation. below is a simple contrived example... there is likely a way to refactor the code, or the api, to avoid this situation, but it became a challenge to solve it to better understand jest. is this possible?

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.bar()
  }

  bar() {
    return 'bar'
  }
}

describe('bar', () => {
  let foo
  let bar

  beforeEach(() => {
    // somehow mock the constructor here
    Foo.prototype.bar = jest.fn()
    foo = new Foo()
  })

  it('should be called once', () => {
    foo.bar()
    expect(foo.bar).toBeCalledTimes(1)
  })
})
```

Comment: `bar()` is not static, so there's no way to call it without creating an instance first. You cannot "initialize" a class.

Comment: @ChrisG - You can create objects with arbitrary prototypes though, including using `Foo.prototype`. :-)

Comment: As someone who wrote a lot of tests like this early in my career, I think you'll regret aggressively mocking things like this. Better to create the instance and check that whatever `bar` was supposed to do was done, rather than validate that `bar` was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to spy the object methods using the `jest.spyOn` method like so:

```js
describe('bar', () => {
  let foo
  let bar

  beforeEach(() => {
    const foo = Object.create(Foo.prototype); // TJ Crowder suggestion
    // Spy object foo, listen to calls to the method bar and mock return
    jest.spyOn(foo, 'bar').mockImplementation(() => /* Custom return */);
    foo.bar();
  })

  it('should be called once', () => {
    foo.bar()
    expect(foo.bar).toBeCalledTimes(1)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object using the same prototype without running the constructor like this:

```
const obj = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
```

[`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) creates an object using the prototype you give it. `Foo.prototype` is the prototype assigned to objects created via `new Foo`, so this does the same thing, but without running the constructor code. `obj` will have all of the `Foo` prototype methods (`bar`, etc.), and `obj instanceof Foo` will be true, but it won't run the constructor.

Example:

```js
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        console.log("Constructor ran"); // <== We don't see this
        this.bar();
    }

    bar() {
        return 'bar';
    }
}

const obj = Object.create(Foo.prototype);
console.log(obj.bar()); // "bar"
console.log(obj instanceof Foo); // true
```

Of course, if the `Foo` constructor code does something essential to the correctness of `Foo` instances, an inevitable side-effect of not running that code is that those essential things won't be done. But your example doesn't have the constructor doing that.

---

Another option would be to split `Foo` into `BaseFoo` and `Foo extends BaseFoo`, with `BaseFoo` having everything except the parts of the constructor code you don't want called when testing. Then you'd use `new BaseFoo` rather than `new Foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Private methods can be mocked for testing purposes, this can be considered a reflection - unless these are `#` native private members that currently cannot be reflected.

In JavaScript, constructor function is a class itself, so mocking a constructor doesn't make much sense. Methods of inherited class that rely on prototype chain can be tested with `Object.create`, like other answers show. Methods of a class or object with no inheritance can be tested by calling them with specific context:

```
// test the class
jest.spyOn(Foo.prototype, 'bar').mockReturnValue(...);
let foo = new Foo();
...
Foo.prototype.bar.mockRestore();

// test the method separately
let fooCtx = {};    
expect(Foo.prototype.bar.call(fooCtx, ...)).toEqual(...);
expect(fooCtx).toEqual({...});
```